# tensorflow:You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float

Tags: tensorflow

my code with the fail:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float
[[{{node Placeholder_1}}]]

Here is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
def get_data(number):
    list_x = []
    list_label = []
    for i in range(number):
        # y=2x+10
        x = np.random.randn(1)
        label = 2 * x + np.random.randn(1) * 0.01 + 10
        list_x.append(x)
        list_label.append(label)
    return list_x, list_label
def inference(x):
    weight = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("weight", [1])
    bias = tf.compat.v1.get_variable("bias", [1])
    y = x * weight + bias
    return y
train_x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float32")
train_label = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float32")
test_x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float32")
test_label = tf.compat.v1.placeholder("float32")
with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("inference"):
    train_y = inference(train_x)
    tf.compat.v1.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    test_y = inference(test_x)
train_loss = tf.square(train_y - train_label)
test_loss = tf.square(test_y - train_label)
opt = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.002)
train_op = opt.minimize(train_loss)
init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
train_data_x, train_data_label = get_data(1000)
test_data_x, test_data_label = get_data(1)
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={train_x: train_data_x[i], train_label: train_data_label[i]})
        if i % 10 == 0:
            test_loss_value = sess.run(test_loss, feed_dict={test_x: test_data_x[0], test_label: test_data_label[0]})
            print("step %d eval loss is %.3f" %(i, test_loss_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code multiple times, nested computation graph will be created. You can view the behavior in tensorboard, graph become bigger and bigger after multiple runs.
You need to reset the graph

Use `tf.reset_default_graph()` and put it before the place where you create the graph